# Get item in the loop in List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I want to select surname of each user in the loop and display it in the textblock, but I'm getting this: `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator2[PhoneApp1.ServiceREference1.Point,System.String]`. How can I correct it?

My WP code is:

```
foreach (ServiceReference1.Point o in someList)
{
    var text = new TextBlock
    {
        Text = someList.Select(x => x.surnm).ToString(),
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange),
    };
}
```

Comment: someList is a List(Of Point)? If yes why do you expect a Point to have a surName?

Comment: Why you are doing a foreach if you are not using "o"? and instead are you creating a list from someList?

Comment: @Steve, I defined this class in my service interface with `surnm` field. I will give that class other name later to be not so confusing.

Comment: @mpacheco, I will use it later to create a multiple pushpins like `MyOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(o.Lat, o.Lon);`

Comment: So you want ONE textblock with ALL the surnames present in the list or a textblock for every surname in the list?

Comment: @Leek You should separate your code then, if not you will create a "text" object for each element in "someList"

Comment: @Steve, I want textblock for every surname in the list. Tim Schmelter has already solved this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already in the loop and have the reference to the current object, so i see no reason for your LINQ query. This should work(presuming that `ServiceReference1.Point` has a `surnm`):

```
foreach (ServiceReference1.Point o in someList)
{
    var text = new TextBlock
    {
        Text = o.surnm.ToString(),
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange),
    };
}
```

Comment: If surnm is a string (which I would assume it was), ToString() is not necessary

Comment: @Hammerstein: i don't know what it is. But `string.ToString` does only `return this`, so it doesn't hurt. But if it's not a string my code would not compile. Since OP seems to be  inexperienced i didn't want to introduce a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.Join`

```
Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, someList.Select(x => x.surnme)),
```